# Compare two soap responses using groovy script

Tags: excel, soapui

I'm using SoapUI free version.I need to compare soap responses. I have expected response in an Excel file. I want to compare the expected response with the actual response from SoapUI and while comparing I need to ignore some fields using groovy script. I can read the data from Excel into a string and response from SoapUI to another string. I need some help in comparing those two values. I didn't get any proper references to compare. I don't have any code for comparison. Please help me with this

```
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.*;
import java.lang.*;
import com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.Assertable.AssertionStatus
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestRequestStep
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import jxl.*
import jxl.write.*
import org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONAssert
import org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONCompareMode
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
/*XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true)
XMLUnit.setIgnoreComments(true)
XMLUnit.setIgnoreDiffBetweenTextAndCDATA(true)
XMLUnit.setNormalizeWhitespace(true)*/
def count=0,i=1,j=1,k=1
def inputFileName,outputFileName
def inputFile = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("inputFileName")
def outputFile = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("outputFileName")
def testStep = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["Properties"]

Workbook inputWB = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(inputFile)) 
Sheet inputSheet = inputWB.getSheet(0)
no_of_rows= inputSheet.getRows().toInteger() 

Workbook existingInputWB=Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(inputFile))
WritableWorkbook outputWB=Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(outputFile),existingInputWB)

testCaseName=testRunner.testCase.name
outputWB.createSheet(testCaseName,2)
WritableSheet sheet_writable = outputWB.getSheet(testCaseName)
jxl.write.Label testStepCell =  new jxl.write.Label(0,0 ,"Test Step")
jxl.write.Label reqUrlCell =  new jxl.write.Label(2,0 ,"Request URL")
jxl.write.Label reqPayloadCell =  new jxl.write.Label(3,0 ,"Request Payload")
jxl.write.Label responseCell =  new jxl.write.Label(4,0 ,"Response")
jxl.write.Label statusCell =  new jxl.write.Label(1,0 ,"Status")
jxl.write.Label reasonCell =  new jxl.write.Label(5,0 ,"Reason")
sheet_writable.addCell(testStepCell)
sheet_writable.addCell(reqUrlCell)
sheet_writable.addCell(reqPayloadCell)
sheet_writable.addCell(responseCell)
sheet_writable.addCell(statusCell)
sheet_writable.addCell(reasonCell)
(0..context.testCase.testStepCount-1).each{
    def step = context.testCase.testStepList[it]
    if ( step instanceof WsdlTestRequestStep) {
        jxl.write.Label stepName =  new jxl.write.Label(0,i ,step.name)
        sheet_writable.addCell(stepName)
        def tr=testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName(step.name)
          def String endPointUrl= tr.getHttpRequest().getResponse().getURL()
        jxl.write.Label reqUrl =  new jxl.write.Label(2,i ,endPointUrl)
        sheet_writable.addCell(reqUrl)
        def payload = context.expand(step.getPropertyValue('Request'))
        jxl.write.Label reqPayload =  new jxl.write.Label(3,i ,payload)
        sheet_writable.addCell(reqPayload)
         def response = context.expand(step.getPropertyValue('Response'))
        jxl.write.Label reqResponse =  new jxl.write.Label(4,i ,response)
        sheet_writable.addCell(reqResponse)
        count=count+1
        i=i+1
    }
}

(0..context.testCase.testStepCount-1).each{
    def step1 = context.testCase.testStepList[it]
    if ( step1 instanceof WsdlTestRequestStep) {
        for(j=1;j<no_of_rows;j++){
            Cell f=inputSheet.getCell(0,j)
             step_name=f.getContents()
             Cell f1=inputSheet.getCell(3,j)
             def String step_response=f1.getContents()
             step_response=step_response.replaceAll(" ","")
             def String response = context.expand(step1.getPropertyValue('Response')) 
             log.info response
             response=response.replaceAll(" ","") 
             /*if(step1.name==step_name&step1.name!=null){

             }*/

        }
    }
}
outputWB.write()
outputWB.close()
existingInputWB.close()
```

Data to be compared:
I want to ignore Auth while comparing

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<env:Header/>
<env:Body>
<ns3:ZeppEsCheckOnlCustIfResponse xmlns:ns3="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
<Auth>36962796d68753535353f2a79637f536865636b6f6e6c636573747f213537353839303631393336353c745543545</Auth>
<number>224354</number>
<Ok>X</Ok>
<Failure/>
</ns3:abcd>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Comment: you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54324008/2986279 , but it will do exact difference,,, if you want specifics then do it node by node or use getNodeValues function by using /* which will get all nodes in a partiuclar XML

Answer (score 1):

There are three main ways to do it.

1) If you want to compare XML with XML, you can use the XMLUnit lib with Groovy. I found this to be brittle.

2) You can also parse the response XML with Groovy's XMLSlurper, and use the GPath to navigate to specific elements and get their values:

```
def responseXML = context.expand('${mySoapRequestStep#Response}')
def Envelope = new XmlSlurper().parseText(responseXML)
log.info Envelope.Body.someNode.nodeIWantValueFor
```

3) The third option is to create a Property Transfer step after your SOAP Request step, and use XPath to store the value in a property. The XPath expression you use in the step is in this format:

```
//*[local-name()='someNode']/*[local-name()='nodeIWantValueFor']/text()
```

On the Property Transfer step you specify where the value is saved, e.g. in a testCaseProperty called nodeIWantValueFor.

Comment: I have added the code used for reading expected response from excel and actual response from soapUI. But unable to proceed on comparing the responses.

Comment: You will have to provide an example of the data values that you want to compare

Comment: @user12435402 it looks like you have two options, you could do a compare in your code, like `if (this.equals(that))` and write the result to a cell or if you write the actual result to the spreadsheet next to the expected result, you can, in a third cell, write a formula that does the test between the cell values, e.g. `=IF(A1=B1,"Pass","Fail")`